# Python server programming

Tags: python, sockets, networking

I am trying a little client server project to get me into network programming but I seem to have got stuck at the first hurdle. I cant seem to get past getting the first line of data only even if its a new connection.

```
#!/usr/bin/python           

import socket               

s = socket.socket()         
host = '192.168.0.233'  # Test Server
port = 7777                
s.bind((host, port))        

s.listen(5)                 
while True:
    c, addr = s.accept()     
    print 'Got connection from', addr
    data = c.recv(2048)
    print(data)
```

If I telnet to the host running the server, the connection opens fine and I see on the server Got connection from addr, but I also only see the first line of data when I sent 4 lines of data,

I thought because its in a loop it should now always be looking for data?

I know im doing something wrong but unsure what.

Im using Python 2.6.6

Answer (score 1):

`recv` needs to be in a loop too, at the moment your code is receiving some data and then waiting for a new connection.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#example has an example of `socket.recv` in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import socket
import threading

def listenForClients(sock):
    while True:
        client, address = sock.accept()
        client.settimeout(5)
        threading.Thread( target = listenToClient, args = (client,address) ).start()

def listenToClient(client, address):
    size = 2048
    while True:
        try:
            data = client.recv(size)
            if data:
                response = "Got connection"
                client.send(response)
            else:
                raise error('Client disconnected')
        except:
            client.close()
            return False

def main(host, port):
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    sock.bind((host, port))
    sock.listen(5)
    listenForClients(sock)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main('192.168.0.233',7777)
```

Here I use a thread for each client. The problem that you have with having `Socket.accept()` in the loop is that it blocks meaning that concurrent access won't work and you'll only be able to talk to one client at a time.

Try running it in the background and sending it messages with:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import socket

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect(('192.168.0.233',7777))
vwhile True:
    data = raw_input("enter a message: ")
    sock.send(data)
    print sock.recv(2048)
```